"Loading module was blocked becasue of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)" on GitHub Pages with Custom Domain
I am new to creating webapps using React + Vite and TypeScript. Recently I have finished my first app and was hoping to deploy it on GitHub pages using a custom domain name. I deployed it using npm run deploy and initially it was working fine after publishing it on https://myusername.github.io/myrepo/, built from the gh-pages branch.
Then I accquired a domain name my-domain.com from a domain name registrar (namecheap in my case), and have set up the corresponding A records and CNAME record as follows.
A records and CNAME config
I returned to github pages and added my-domain.com to the field under custom domain. After the site was live, I went to the domain and found out all my React Components are not visible (i.e. empty screen). I checked the developer tools and see that I am getting Loading module from “https://my-domain.com/myrepo/assets/index-DvHFCQ4H.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).Similarly, the index-D83KZPnh.css was also blocked because of the same reason.
Screenshot of Dev tools
I have gone through some of the post on SO and followed a fair amount of tutorials for possible fixes but still stumble upon this problem. I looked in the github pages docs in Managing a custom domain for your GitHub Pages site and tried adding a CNAME file with my-domain.com in it only, but this also doesn't fix the issue.
Has anyone encountered this before and could help or provide a possible fix? Any help would be appreciated.

I wrote a tutorial on using a custom domain with GitHub pages to host a Vite+React app at https://github.com/cesardgm/my-vite-app. From the tutorial:
Configuring AWS Route 53 Domain with GitHub Pages
Prepare a favicon.ico file and place it at the root level of your repository.
Domain Registration and DNS Configuration:

Purchase a domain through AWS Route 53.
Navigate to the hosted zone for your purchased domain.
Create a Simple Record of type A:

Set Alias to No
Enter the following IP addresses for Value/Route traffic to:
185.199.108.153
185.199.109.153
185.199.110.153
185.199.111.153





GitHub Domain Verification:

Go to your GitHub account settings > Pages (under Code, planning, and automation).
Click "Add a verified domain" and enter your AWS Route 53 domain.
Copy the provided TXT record subdomain and value.
In AWS Route 53, create a TXT record:

Subdomain: Replace www with the GitHub-provided value (typically _github-pages-challenge-{username})
Value: Paste the GitHub-provided code


Create a CNAME record:

Type: CNAME
Value/Route traffic to: {username}.github.io


Return to GitHub and click "Verify".

Local Repository Configuration:

Create a file named CNAME (without any extension) in the root directory of your local repository.
Add a single line to the file: www.{customDomain}.{extension}

Update Vite Configuration:

Modify vite.config.ts:

Change the base property from /my-vite-app/ to /



Rebuild and Redeploy:
npm run build
npm run deploy


GitHub Repository Settings:

Navigate to your repository's settings > Pages (under Code and automation).
Under "Custom domain", enter your verified domain.
Click "Save" and enable "Enforce HTTPS".


Completion: Your Vite + React app is now deployed and accessible via your custom domain with HTTPS enforced.


Notes:

Replace {username} with your GitHub username.
Replace {customDomain} and {extension} with your actual domain name and top-level domain.
Ensure all DNS changes are propagated, which may take up to 48 hours.
Regularly check and renew your domain registration and SSL certificate to maintain uninterrupted service.


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
